# Creating subplots with Taipy

Tags: taipy

I’m trying to find some documentation about subplots in Taipy.

Is it possible to do this with Taipy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have subplots. For example, for polar charts, an example can be found in the Taipy documentation [here](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/charts/polar/#specifying-the-angular-range).

However, we recommend using the [layout](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/layout/) block to create subplots. See below for a simple example:

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui

# Sample small plot definition
data = {
    "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "y": [5, 40, 80, 120, 160],
}

# Sample small plot definition
data2 = {
    "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "y": [1, 4, 3, 10, 20],
}

md = """
<|layout|columns=1 1|
<|{data}|chart|>

<|{data2}|chart|>

<|{data}|chart|type=bar|>

<|{data2}|chart|type=bar|>
|>
"""

Gui(md).run()
```

[image]